# How Automatically Try again after 2 second if not match abul == abul?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am trying matching abul == abul until not going matching in my name list.

```
If ("abul" == "abul")
{
do my work
}
else 
{
wait 2 second then try again 
}
```

How possible this any idea?

Comment: use a loop with a Thread.Sleep(2000) or use a timer. i am assuming that that is not the actual condition.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense; that condition will always return true. Could you try to explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: why have you tagged this webbrowser-control?

Comment: I am trying browser progressber detection if progressber finishing show done then starting my code otherwise waiting.